# jest trying to parse .css

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jestjs

I have a problem with jest in which no matters what I do it keeps trying to parse the css files as javascript.

The files build properly with webpack.

I have the following configuration for jest

```
"jest": {
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^.*[.](css|CSS)$": "../jest/styleMock.js"
    }
  },
```

I also tried a script preprocessor to strip the css from the imports:

```
 "jest": {
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "scriptPreprocessor": "../node_modules/jest-css-modules"
  },
```

It keeps throwing the error.

```
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){.button {
                                                                                             ^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The best solution is to use a `moduleNameMapper` line in your Jest config, as [described in the Jest docs](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/webpack.html).

A minimal "ignore css" jest config, in `package.json`, might like this

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": { "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/assets/css/__mocks__/styleMock.js" }
  },
```

Then styleMock.js is just this

```
module.exports = {};
```

Comment: Seems like this will only work for the files directly imported in the jest test file. If you import a module that imports a css file then it will still break.

Comment: @Edward that's not true, it works for me for css files imported by the module that my test imports

Comment: @gaurav5430 which version of node/jest are you using?

Comment: jest ^24 and node 8

Comment: The Jest docs now recommend using the "identity-obj-proxy" package in conjunction with moduleNameMapper, which has some benefits for snapshot testing: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack#mocking-css-modules

Comment: I was getting an error about `specified in the "transform" object of Jest configuration  must export a `process` or `processAsync` or `createTransformer` function.` Following the Jest docs, I was able to get it to ignore css by changing my styleMock.js to:
```
module.exports = {
  process() {
    return {
      code: `module.exports = {};`,
    };
  },
};
```

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if it's the best way, but considering I've been stuck here for a while, I am posting the solution.

In order to fix it, I had to do two steps:

1) The @Jonathan Stray solution so add a `moduleNameMapper` pointing to a js mock (see his response for more details)

2) Then I had to install the `jest-css-modules-transform` plugin, and add it in the jest configuration inside the `package.json` like below:

```
"jest": {
    //...
    "transform": {
        ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-css-modules-transform",
        //...
    },
    //...
}
```

Comment: by using jest-css-modules-transform you are transforming the css files to return something else. was it not enough for you to just "ignore" css files by using moduleNameMapper ? and if you are using transform, is moduleNameMapper even required ?

Answer (score 5):

I'm using "jest-css-modules-transform" and it's work well.

1. I had to install the jest-css-modules-transform plugin :

```
npm i --save-dev jest-css-modules-transform
```

or with yarn

```
yarn add -D jest-css-modules-transform
```

2. Then add it in the jest configuration inside the jest.config.s like below:

```js
module.exports = {
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/.next/", "<rootDir>/node_modules/"],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/setupTests.tsx"],
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
        '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss)$': 'jest-css-modules-transform'
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [babel CLI](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/)?

In my preprocessor I use `babel-core` and `canCompile` function from `babel-core->utils` to transform my code and also ignore other files than .js, .es, .jsx etc.

```
var babel = require('babel-core');
var canCompile = babel.util.canCompile

module.exports = {
    process: function (src, filename) {
    if (!canCompile(filename)) {
        return ''; //ignore this file
    }
```

Maybe your code also isn't transformed and that's why you have `SyntaxError` ([babel.transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/api/))? Look also at [custom preprocessor](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react.html#custom-preprocessors) in jest.

Comment: I actually found the solution it had to be with styleMock and fileMock jest files, I'll post such answer later as I manage to get access again to the repository.

Comment: I lost access to the repository :c but from what I remember there had to be something in the styleMock and fileMock jest files that tell it not to parse anything.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to update my styleMock to use the code syntax by following [the official docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation#typescript-with-type-checking).

`jest.config.js`

```
  transform: {
    '.(css|less)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js',
  },
```

`__mocks__/styleMock.js`

```
module.exports = {
  process() {
    return {
      code: `module.exports = {};`,
    };
  },
};
```

Comment: thank you It helped me resolve the issue